# Qual a diferença de downcase e downcase!

Tags: ruby

Estou começando com Ruby e me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
 user_input = gets.chomp
 user_input.donwcase!
```

A minha dúvida é porque de utilizar o ponto de exclamação depois do downcase.

Comment: Acredito que você pode achar aqui a resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709229/difference-between-downcase-and-downcase-in-ruby

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pontos de exclamação em Ruby são usados para indicar métodos "perigosos". No caso do método `downcase!` ele modifica o próprio objeto. Outro exemplo notório é do `exit` (que dá chance para a aplicação terminar normalmente e executar o método `at_exit`) vs `exit!` (terminação imediata).

A versão "segura" do método `downcase` volta uma cópia modificada da *string* sem alterar o conteúdo da mesma:

```
foo = "UMA STRING" 
bar = foo.downcase
puts foo            # UMA STRING
puts bar            # uma string
```

Já a versão com ponto de exclamação é utilizada para alterar a própria *string*:

```
foo = "UMA STRING"
foo.downcase!
puts foo            # uma string
```

---

**Fonte**: [SOE - Why are exclamation marks used in Ruby methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods)

Answer (score 1):

No padrão da standart library do ruby, o Bang (`!`) quer dizer que ele não modifica a variável que está chamando o método.

Mas existem outras implementações para ele, por exemplo, no Active Record o Bang é utilizado para simbolizar que o metodo vai lançar uma exceção ao invés de retornar um simples `false`. [Fonte](https://riptutorial.com/ruby-on-rails/example/9285/activerecord-bang-----methods)